# Primefaces: autocomplete in hidden h:panel group element not initialized

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsf, primefaces, autocomplete

My autocomplete is inside the  h:panel id="result" which is rendered when the search condition is true .The input field of the p:autocomplete is displayed when search condition is true with the error "VM1776:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: PrimeFaces is not defined" and list also  not populating

But when I submit the form the validaton error display required autocomplete then only autocomplete works fine and populate list

here is code of xhtml

```
<p:autoComplete id="name"
                        value="#{regBean.name}"
                        forceSelection="true"
                        completeMethod="#{regBean.getName}"
                        styleClass=" input-adjust #{ component.valid ? 'required-mark-border-ok' : 'required-mark-border-error'}"
                     required="true"
                         rendered="true"
                        />
```

Comment: The first time the page is rendered, will there then be any primefaces components rendered at all? At least 1 is needed for automatically importing the primefaces js and css. If not, put a component somewhere which will always be rendered, for example p:outputPanel with display:none or similar

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm out of time to propose a solution, but I have a problem exactly like this: an autocomplete inside a panel that be showed only if a condition is true.

In my case, this problem was solved using @ViewScoped on the bean.